# Remove focus from mat-select after selection change

Tags: angular, select, focus

In .html file i have selector:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select #selector(selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event.value)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let test of tests" [value]="test">
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

In .ts file I have:

```
  @ViewChild('selector', { static: false }) selector: MatSelect

  onSelectionChange(value: any) {
    this.selector.focused = false;
  }
```

It doesn't work because focused is read only parameter, but how to achieve this effect other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MatSelect expose [close](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect) method.

**Try this:**

```
 onSelectionChange(value: any) {
    this.selector.close();
  }
```

Comment: I really don't know why I didn't came up with this idea... Thank you!!

Comment: If you were to pass `$event` into your selection change (i.e. `(selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"`) then you could use  `onSelectionChange(event) { event.source.close(); }`